# Ethernet performance issue : "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" Network LAN Ethernet Driver VS "Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS" Network LAN Ethernet Driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, ethernet, intel

Please refer

Ubuntu 18 as - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Ubuntu 20 as - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Ubuntu 20 on Lenovo y700 (https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-y700-series/Ideapad-Y700-15/p/88IPY700618 ) doesn't give Ethernet performance like Ubnutu 18.

LAN driver of Ubuntu 20 doesn't perform like Ubuntu 18.

1gbps connection gives 940 mbps download on Ubuntu 18 vs <500 mbps on Ubuntu 20.

Main reason to notify: Ubuntu 20 can be used to host internet applications in cloud and it won't be preferred to have server performance slower due to limitation of ethernet driver. Definitely many factors are there and server version might be perfectly fine vs desktop version of Ubuntu 20.

This is biggest drawback and keeps me on Ubuntu 18. Wifi drivers good and I understand wifi hardware receptors limit which might be around 500 mbps. I do not face any wifi driver problems like other questions I see on internet.

Always in confusion to use Ubuntu 18 or 20 as :

Ubuntu 18 has issue of always Fan ON with NVIDIA

vs

Ubuntu 20 has issue of ethernet driver performance which limits internet speed and performs slower than Ubuntu 18.

---

```
Output of commands on my Ubuntu 18

ru@ru-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3831]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169


ru@ru-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~$ uname -r

4.15.0-123-generic

ru@ru-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~$ sudo lshw

[sudo] password for ru: 
ru-lenovo-ideapad-y700-15isk
    description: Notebook
    product: 80NV (LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK
    serial: PF0EP47D
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK uuid=2267789A-787F-E511-BA4C-507B9D5E070B
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Allsparks 5A
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: SDK0J40709 WIN
       serial: PF0EP47D
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: CDCN54WW
          date: 06/13/2017
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3445MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: M471A1G43DB0-CPB
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 15191694
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: M471A1G43DB0-CPB
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 2
             serial: 15191695
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:93000000-93ffffff ioport:80000000(size=301989888)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:94300000-9430ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-123-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: CORSAIR K70 RGB MK.2 LOW PROFILE Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
                   vendor: Corsair
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 3.24
                   serial: 05008027AF081CE75891B270F5001BC4
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mouse
                   product: Microsoft USB Optical Mouse
                   vendor: PixArt
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: Lenovo EasyCamera
                   vendor: NXP (Philips Semi, Signetics)
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 12.18
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: b
                   bus info: usb@1:b
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-123-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: Ultra Fit
                   vendor: SanDisk
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   logical name: scsi4
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 0401afd9c38eabbedc76169110d5bda8b99e8fdf27e7dbbd02cb83c458d915c63226000000000000
                   capabilities: usb-3.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: Ultra Fit
                      vendor: SanDisk
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sdc
                      version: 1.00
                      serial: 0401afd9c38eabbedc76
                      size: 28GiB (30GB)
                      capabilities: removable
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-medium
                         physical id: 0
                         logical name: /dev/sdc
                         size: 28GiB (30GB)
                         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                         configuration: signature=15f006ae
                       *-volume:0
                            description: Windows FAT volume
                            vendor: mkfs.fat
                            physical id: 2
                            logical name: /dev/sdc2
                            version: FAT12
                            serial: 1ac3-20ed
                            size: 15EiB
                            capabilities: primary boot fat initialized
                            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
                       *-volume:1
                            description: EXT4 volume
                            vendor: Linux
                            physical id: 3
                            logical name: /dev/sdc3
                            logical name: /media/ru/writable
                            version: 1.0
                            serial: a394eff0-cf97-445c-bc33-b700cccfd261
                            size: 26GiB
                            capacity: 26GiB
                            capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                            configuration: created=2020-07-12 17:26:01 filesystem=ext4 label=writable lastmountpoint=/root/var/crash modified=2020-11-21 18:48:22 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2020-11-21 18:48:22 state=mounted
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:9432a000-9432afff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:94328000-94329fff memory:9432d000-9432d0ff ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5088(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:9432b000-9432b7ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:94200000-942fffff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
                vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:94201000-94201fff memory:94200000-942007ff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:94100000-941fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                logical name: wlp8s0
                version: 3a
                serial: a4:34:d9:32:b0:fe
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-123-generic firmware=34.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:131 memory:94100000-94101fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:94000000-940fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: enp9s0
                version: 15
                serial: 50:7b:9d:5e:07:0b
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.182 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:94324000-94327fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:132 memory:94320000-94323fff memory:94310000-9431ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:9432c000-9432c0ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SAMSUNG MZNLN128
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3L0Q
             serial: S22XNXAGA02179
             size: 119GiB (128GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=26265439-517d-473c-b88f-2b5898fcb37a logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT32
                serial: fba5-9004
                size: 1022MiB
                capacity: 1023MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /home
                version: 1.0
                serial: 515346ee-deac-4a80-b610-6faa3158f22f
                size: 34GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-09-16 20:41:22 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2020-11-21 18:32:13 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2020-11-21 18:32:13 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /home2
                version: 1.0
                serial: 096eae9a-a098-4864-810f-cfc27898906b
                size: 30GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-10-04 10:16:34 filesystem=ext4 label=home2 lastmountpoint=/home2 modified=2020-11-21 18:32:13 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2020-11-21 18:32:13 state=mounted
           *-volume:3
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 1bc3863d-45c9-43aa-8818-34083956d624
                size: 53GiB
                capacity: 53GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-09-19 16:18:10 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2020-11-21 18:32:11 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2020-11-21 18:32:11 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10SPCX-24H
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1A02
             serial: WD-WX11A957RXTP
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=3848de97-9627-4822-9637-8ba83a3aad11 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /mnt/storage
                version: 3.1
                serial: d2169a7f-681f-2442-a1a6-c9e5b8a8c5e8
                size: 799GiB
                capacity: 799GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-11-10 05:25:56 filesystem=ntfs label=STORAGE mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 name=Basic data partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                logical name: /mnt/sh
                version: 3.1
                serial: a6895502-92c1-684d-bdc8-84658bc79493
                size: 86GiB
                capacity: 86GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2010-05-03 22:24:57 filesystem=ntfs label=SH mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sdb3
                logical name: /mnt/exe
                version: 3.1
                serial: d8374315-36a4-2347-811a-2a5bd1f22f47
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-12-22 03:34:26 filesystem=ntfs label=EXE modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:3
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sdb4
                version: 1
                serial: acbf1615-d7b6-4996-9832-91844cd93640
                size: 30GiB
                capacity: 30GiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap label=swap pagesize=4095
```

Comment: Ubuntu has two rather different releases, Ubuntu with *yy.mm* are used with servers & desktops, and there is a smaller-footprint *yy* release that is *snap* only so be careful with switching *yy.mm* releases (like 20.04) with a *yy* release (such as 20). Ubuntu Core 20 won't use *debs* for example. Most *drivers* however are kernel modules, so are linked to the kernel itself; so a 18.04 LTS with HWE enabled IS using the same kernel as Ubuntu 20.04 with GA kernel. But your mixing two different products (*yy.mm* and *yy*) makes it somewhat confusing as there are differences/complexities.

Comment: A Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the GA kernel will be using an older kernel (4.15) than Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with HWE or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GA) which both use 5.4.  Please try and keep factual (20 is not the same as 20.04) & use full details (18.04 with GA or HWE kernel, or just use the numbers if you're not familiar with general/hardware-enablement etc).

Comment: Neither your question nor the link give us any details as to the ethernet hardware or driver. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a different product to Ubuntu Core 20.  Ubuntu releases with *yy.mm* format use *debs* by default, but can also use *snaps*.  Ubuntu releases with *yy* in their name are *snap* only based releases; so Ubuntu 20 implies a different system to Ubuntu 20.04 (Ubuntu has had *yy* releases since 2016; they are specialist releases for IoT appliances, devices or cloud use, as cut-down (less functionality) thus light & fast).  Please correct your question to use one of Ubuntu Core 20, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (not an non-existing Ubuntu 20 that implies a *snap* only release)

Comment: You can edit your own question (it mentions Ubuntu 18 & Ubuntu 20 which is closest to Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20, but that's not what you mean).  Also extra detail such as the `lshw` detail should be added to your question (it allows better formatting, can be edited etc).  *I can then delete my coments on non-existent releases!*

Comment: Added details and formatted question details. Thank you