# How to remove Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) when installed along side Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, uninstall

I had Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) as dual boot.

As Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) has very poor Ethernet performance vs Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS I want to remove it.

What are ideal steps to remove Ubuntu?

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 Grub.
Delete Ubuntu 20.04 partitions.
Edit the Grub menu to remove the Ubuntu 20.04 option

Comment: Should try to find out why it is poor.  Might just be a simple fix.

Comment: Great if anyone can point on ethernet driver test with more than 1gbs bandwidth. Detailed poor performance scenario is in below question. 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287259/ethernet-performance-issue-ubuntu-20-04-lts-network-lan-ethernet-driver-vs

May be I will build aws ec2 image with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and will post result but not sure how do I test in server OS. In desktop version I can test in chrome browser by accessing speedtest.net website.

Tried to delete partition and faced broken booting, fixed with boot-repair utility and Ubuntu 18 bootable USB.